# Purchase Paris Visite "zones 1-3" to travel from CDG to Paris city center?

Tags: trains, france, paris

Since I will stay in Paris for 5 days, I am thinking to buy unlimited travel passes (Paris Visite "zones1-3"). I need also to use RER B to travel from CDG airport to paris center. But the airport is located in zone 5.

Does it mean that I can not use Paris Visite "zones1-3" to travel from airport to center?

In this case which ticket type should I also buy to travel from CDG using RER B?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use your zone 1-3 carte to go from zone 5.

You may buy a zone 5 - zone 3 ticket at CDG if you already have your zone 1-3 carte.

Comment: What does it cost to buy a zone 3 - zone 5 ticket for one time? What is the name of this ticket?

Comment: A ticket to Paris cost 9,75 euros. The last station on the RER B line in the third zone is "le blanc mesnil", but it is not a nice place for tourism... From that point, the trip to the airport cost 6 euros (origin-destination ticket, sold by machines or people in stations). See [transilien.com](http://www.transilien.com/itineraire/rechercheitineraire/recherche?searchType=0&typeDepart=STOP_AREA&depart=LE+BLANC+MESNIL++++&typeArrivee=STOP_AREA&arrivee=AEROPORT+CHARLES+DE+GAULLE+1++++++&sens=1)

Comment: Also take a look at http://www.aeroportsdeparis.fr/passagers/acces/paris-charles-de-gaulle/transports-en-commun : the bus line 350 can take you to Gare de l'Est (in Paris) and the bus line 351 to "nation" (in Paris too) both for 6€. The bus line 19 can take you to Torcy for 2€, but it is far in the east of Paris, in zone5...Useful if you stay at Disneyland, useless otherwise.